# Pinging and Accessing Websites

Tags: networking, ping

The IP address of [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) is 216.58.214.4. I can easily access this site when I enter it in the URL. But when I ping it on the command line, I get a request timeout. Likewise, when I ping an IP address and it is successful, I can't access the site. What is going on?

Note I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you "access" this site you use HTTP or HTTPS, which uses TCP packets. If you ping it, then you use ICMP packets.

Those are different types of packets, and there can be firewalls on the route from your Windows PC to the Google website, for example on your Windows PC, your home router, your ISP, or even the Internet backbone connection between your ISP and Google (though that's rare).

Any of those could have been configured to block ICMP "ping" packets.

If you want those to go through, check all Firewalls you control if they block those or not, and turn off blocking. If they still don't go through, some Firewall you don't control blocks them.